# jQuery UI Multiselect Next - onChange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, multi-select

I have jQuery UI Multiselect Next http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next
I want to fire an event whenever the selection changes in any way.

This example doesn't work:

```
$('#countries').change(function() {
alert('Hi');
});
```

So basically, how can I fire an event on any selection change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply a feedback function to handle the selected events as an init option.

```
$('.selector').multiselect({ selected: function(event, ui) { alert($(ui.option).val() + " has been selected"); } });

$('.selector').multiselect({ deselected: function(event, ui) { alert($(ui.option).val() + " has been deselected"); } });
```

Bind to the selected event of type multiselectselected.

```
$('.selector').bind('multiselectselected', function(event, options) {
  ...   // ui.option is the DOMOption node of ui.sender
});

$('.selector').bind('multiselectdeselected', function(event, ui) {
  ...   // ui.option is the DOMOption node of ui.sender
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('#countries').mouseleave(function() {
 alert('Hi');
});
```